# customErrors with redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" do not work on shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, shared-hosting

I am trying to setup custom error pages for my site (ASP.NET 4, integrated pipeline).

Everything works properly on local machine but custom error pages for `.aspx` pages do not get shown on shared hosting (I see default error pages).

If I change `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` to `redirectMode="ResponseRedirect"` everything works properly on local and shared machine.

`error.aspx` is a real file that resides next to `web.config` file (in the root of the site). Site has no `Global.asax` file.

Local machine runs IIS 7.5, I do not use routing (at least consciously) and shared hosting tells that `Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319`

Could you please tell me what might be the reason for such different behavior and what should I do to resolve the issue.

Here is excerpt from my `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />      
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: What are you running locally? IIS 7 or 7.5? There are several differences when it comes custom errors. Also, are you using routing?

Comment: @ScottE locally I'm running IIS 7.5 and I do not use routing (at least consciously)

Comment: Also, make sure the app pool is not running in classic mode vs pipeline, otherwise the system.webServer section won't get hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After loooong discussion with the hosting provider it turned out that:

- my approach is fine
- but it won't work as expected because **hosting provider disabled such ability** via `machine.config`.

So, never underestimate number of provider gotchas.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following comment in my web.config:

for IIS 7.5, use errorMode="Custom"; use responseMode="ExecuteURL" if using routing, otherwise use responseMode="Redirect"

Just don't ask me to explain, because I don't know! I just sorted it out by trial and error.

Comment: `httpErrors` part works properly on both machines. non-existent pages like site.com/1 are getting handled properly. it's `customErrors` part that brings unexpected behavior on shared hosting (pages like site.com/1.aspx are not getting handled as expected)

Comment: /1 isn't really a .net resource, so I think you'll have to use: <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>